# Javascript If statement not acknowledged

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Here is the code

```
setHighScore: function() {
    var highScore = 0;
    if (!window.snake || !window.fpsls || !window.fmlts) {
        return;
    }
    if (++bot.tickCounter >= 20) {
            bot.tickCounter = 0;
    var currentScore = parseInt(Math.floor(150 * (window.fpsls[window.snake.sct] +
    window.snake.fam / window.fmlts[window.snake.sct] - 1) - 50) / 10);
    if (Number(currentScore) > Number(highScore)) {
        highScore = currentScore;
        window.localStorage.setItem('highScoreLoc', highScore);
        console.log('Current Score: ' + currentScore);
        }
    }
},

onFrameUpdate: function() {
    // Botstatus overlay
    var generalStyle = '<span style = "opacity: 0.35";>';
    window.fps_overlay.innerHTML = generalStyle + 'FPS: ' +
        userInterface.framesPerSecond.getFPS() + '</span>';

    if (window.position_overlay && window.playing) {
        // Display Personal High Score
        userInterface.setHighScore();
        window.scoreHuD.innerHTML = generalStyle +
        'Your High Score: ' + parseInt(Number(window.localStorage.getItem('highScoreLoc')));

        // Display the X and Y of the snake
        window.position_overlay.innerHTML = generalStyle +
            'X: ' + (Math.round(window.snake.xx) || 0) +
            ' Y: ' + (Math.round(window.snake.yy) || 0) +
            '</span>';
    }
```

It's meant to check if the score is bigger than the high score then save the new high score (if its bigger) and after that print it on screen. But it isn't for some reason

line 10 is the if statement
the 2 lines above it are to find the current score and i know it outputs the current score because of line 13

Its Tampermonkey

and the actual script https://github.com/Classicanon/Slither.io-bot/blob/master/bot.user.js For (Slither.io)

Comment: what is the error, and what do you expect?

Comment: Is it only printing the last score as the highest score?

Comment: what if statement?

Comment: is it this one?  if (Number(currentScore) > Number(highScore)) {

Comment: Your conditional statements are fine, cant figure out the math you are using to calculate currentScore, are you sure that its not resulting in a negative number or zero, because if so, then the `if (Number(currentScore) > Number(highScore))` will return false every time.

Comment: @Regis Portalez i expected it to check if the current score is bigger then the saved highscore but instead it just passes through

Comment: @Mike yes it is only printing that

Comment: @Thorarins yep exactly

Comment: @ClassicToxin This is not an issue with if statement. It's just that you are initialising highScore as 0, every time the function is called - `var highScore = 0;`. So, there's no previous score stored to be compared and almost every score that is compared becomes highestScore because it gets compared to a zero. So, in the end you get the last score as the highest Score.

Comment: Thx @mike so just get rid of that or ...

Comment: depends on your use case. You might declare `highScore` as property of your object, or perhaps simply making it global by removing the `var` before it might work. You just want to maintain this variable's value across multiple calls to this function.